# Access Flex Application ActiveX / ExternalInterface in seperate process from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, apache-flex

I need to fetch a flex application from a process in C#.

**How can i get access to the externalInterfaceAPI when the flex application is running as a Application?**

EDIT: After further reading it looks like it is possible, as from what i understood, a flex stand alone application is a ActiveX "container", so what i need is to get access to the ActiveX container, and from there the externalInterface API.

I hope i explained my problem for you to understand.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT. Anyone know if it is even possible? (without doing something crazy)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to search for '.NET Flash Projector' or 'C# flash projector'.  I know this is possible, and a quick googling has a few examples if you feel like reading through them.

Good luck.

Comment: I think you misred something, im not looking to integrate the flash / flex in my application, i want to communicate with an existing flex application.

Comment: Reading through your description, it sounds like you're trying to run a flex app as an exe on top of a C# app.  If the flex app and the c# exe are completely independent, that's a different manimal.

There are ways to do this as well.  Funny that Darron Schall was doing flash in '05: http://www.darronschall.com/weblog/2005/03/exploring-localconnection-for-c-and-flash.cfm

[I didn't read through the example, he probably grabs the serialized localConnection data from the locale that flashPlayer copies localConnection send() calls to disk.]  This, of course, is one of many solutions.